# Cubic equation and points on an elliptic curve

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, diophantine-equations, elliptic-curves, cubics

Let $$\theta=\sqrt[3]2,K=Q(\theta),R=Z[\theta],$$ where R is the ring of integers (has class number 1).I was trying to solve the diophantine equation $x^3+2y^3=3z^3,$ which becomes equivalent to $$x+y\theta=\epsilon.\lambda.\alpha^3,$$ where $\epsilon$ is a unit and $\lambda$ is the prime $1+\theta$ (we need only consider when the unit is 1, since $1+\theta+\theta^2=\frac{\lambda^3}{3}$) .In a [paper](http://jtnb.cedram.org/cedram-bin/article/JTNB_2012__24_3_691_0.pdf) by Franz Lemmermeyer,particularly the sixth section, it is proved that the classes of so called "binomial" cubes (their $\theta^2$ component is 0) are in bijection with rational points of an elliptic curve.Can we do something similar to the equation above, if we substitute $$\alpha=A+B\theta+C\theta^2?$$Would this be enough to solve the equation in relatively prime integers x,y,z?It becomes equivalent to the following:

$$A^2B+A^2C+B^2A+2B^2C+2C^2A+2C^2B=0,$$ which is homogenous, so we can divide by the cube of one of the three.I am stuck here, though.

Note: a particular paper by T. Nagell seems relevant, but I cannot access it.It is called "Solution complète de quelques équations cubiques à deux indeterminées." Journal de Mathématiques Pures et Appliquées 4 (1925): 209-270.

Answer (score 1):

HINT.-There are infinitely many rational solutions because of the equivalence (very known on elliptic curves $X^3+Y^3=AZ^3$)
$$x+y=z\iff(9xy^2+(y-x)^3)^3+(9x^2y-(y-x)^3)^3=xyz(3(x^2+xy+y^2))^3\qquad (*)$$

In fact, $(1,1,1)$ is an obvious solution of $x^3+2y^3=3z^3$ so we have 
$$1+2=3\iff (9\cdot1\cdot4+1)^3+(9\cdot1^2\cdot2-1)^3=6(3(1+2+2^2))^3$$ i.e.
$$1+2=3\iff37^3+17^3=6(21)^3\qquad(**)$$
Our obvious solution $(1,1,1)$  corresponds to the generator $G_0=(37,17,21)$ of the elliptic curve $X^3+Y^3=6Z^3$ which is known has rank equal to $1$ hence all its rational points are given by $nG_0$ where $nG_0=\underbrace{G_0+G_0+\cdots +G_0}_{n\text{ times}}$ and $+$ is the sum of the group all elliptic curve is.

In order to find possible integer solutions of  $x^3+2y^3=3z^3$ other than $(1,1,1)$ we can calculate $3nG_0$  and compare the resulting expression using  $(*)$. However this requires calculations of degree polynomials $ (3n)^2$, in particular for $3G$ we should use degree $9$.
Calculations of rational points with elliptic curves always involves big integers (Who wanted to do it can use the formulas for the addition on $X^3+Y^3=AZ^3$. There are infinitely many rational solutions but only finitely many integer solutions and maybe just one, the $(1,1,1)$.

**Historic note** (**).-Legendre in his "*Essai sur la théorie des nombres*" (Second edition 1808) erroneously added $6$ to his first $2,3,4$ and $5$ not representable as sum of two rational cubes.

Comment: There is the solution (5,-4,-1)

Comment: Also how did you come up with that equivalence equation?

Comment: Also, since $x^3+y^3=6z^3$ has one solution, then it has infinitely many solutions, but that doesn't help with the original equation, except if that transformation is surjective, but i don't think it is.

Comment: @Bogdan Simeonov: with your solution $(5,-4,-1)$ you get from $(*)$ the solution $(2237723,-1805723,960540)$ of $X^3+Y^3=6Z^3$ so this point is a "multiple" $nG_0$ of $G_0$ for some $n$ because the rank of this curve is equal to $1$ (the most probable is $n=3$ according with I have said; it is almost impossible for $n=6$ because the points would be in accordance with a polinomial of degree $6^2=36$ and this point seems too small for such a degree).

Comment: But x^3+y^3=6z^3 has infinitely many integer solutions (see T.Nagell's Introduction to Number Theory), whereas i dont think our original does.Also, the method you presented is not very close to what I had in mind, and Im not sure it solves the problem completely.What you have said is that if x,y,z are an integer solution to our original equation, then we can construct an integer solution to a^3+b^3=6c^3, which has infinetely many integer solutions.What i had in mind was close to the ideas in the paper I linked

Comment: You have a perspective error. Of course, any curve that is not of rank 0 has an infinity of "integer solutions" (with quotation marks) because it is in homogeneous coordinates. But what counts for the curves $X^3 + Y^3= = AZ^3$ is the representation of the integer A as a sum of rationals, i.e. solutions of $A = x^3 + y^3$ and in that case our curve with $A=6$ has no integer solution. None elliptical curve has an infinity of integer points (Siegel's result) but an infinite number of rational points when its rank is not zero.

Comment: @Bogdan: Just in case it interests you,  the point $(2237723,-1805723,960540)$ of $X^3+Y^3=6Z^3$ corresponding to your solution $(5,-4,-1)$ is $2G_0$. (it corresponds to a polynomial of degree $4$).

Comment: "Theorem 128. If a is an integer > 2 which is not divisible by the cube of any prime, the Diophantine equation
x3- y3 == a z3
has either no solution or infinitely many solutions in relatively prime integers y and y, with z different from 0."

Comment: this is from nagell's introduction to number theory page 246

Comment: So no rational non-integer solution..... then the theorem on finitude of integer points in elliptic curves  is false…….You are confusing things: in homogeneous coordinates, of course ALL points are "integer". It is an illusion to believe that the intrinsic difficulty of the arithmetic of elliptic curves can be avoided with means other than their group law. Your approach attempt is fully developed in the classic paper by E. S. Selmer "The diophantine equation $ax^3+by^3+cz^3=0$” Acta Math. (Stockh.) 85 (1951) p.203-362. Good luck dear friend. No more comments.

Comment: Thank you for all the insight